# почему response scrapy не показывает информацию с страницы

Tags: python, парсер, scrapy

Пытаюсь достать информацию с страницы (json), но скрапи как будто не видит страницу, подскажите пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

ссылка на саму страницу
https://quizium.ru/ajaxrating?search_team=&season=all&city=7&json=1&offset=0
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: с параметром json=0 в адресе - то же?

Comment: Да, с параметром тоже

Comment: Согласно сообщению что на скриншоте, `DEBUG: Forbidden by robots.txt`, получается что данная страница запрещена к кровлингу в `robots.txt` файле, потому Скрэпи послушно пропускает эту страницу. Думаю у скрэпи есть какой то флаг отключения проверки `robots.txt` на сервере, если нет, то нужно использовать какой то другой кровлер.

Comment: @Arty, Спасибо за помощь!